# React-Native KeyCloak - can't find variable: document

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, keycloak

I want to integrate Keycloak login to my React Native app.
Here is a part of the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { user, isLogout } = this.props;
  const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
  keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(authenticated => {
  this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated })
})
```

React can't handle the json with the login details. Here is example of the json:

```
{
  "realm": "MyApp",
  "auth-server-url": "http://192.168.0.109:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "my-app-client-id",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

A test with Postman is successful.
As I tried to find some info about this, it seems something with the DOM.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've similar issue. I'll try with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-keycloak/native

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the keycloak script file within the **index.html**.

`<script src="http://rawgit.com/keycloak/keycloak-js-bower/master/dist/keycloak.min.js" ></script>`